# Display time on iOS device wrongly using Material-UI-Picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an [example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-time-picker-4l6l1).
I think there are some problems about timezone momentjs

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <div className="pickers">
      <InlineTimePicker
        value={this.state.time}
        onChange={time => this.handleTimeChange(time)}
        keyboard
        placeholder="hh:mm"
        ampm={false}
        mask={[/\d/, /\d/, ":", /\d/, /\d/]}
      />
    </div>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

when I input 01:00, the Expected result is show 01:00 not 08:00. I'm in Vietnam

Please use: `import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/moment";`

Comment: You initialize `this.state.time` with date in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm` but then set it to `HH:mm`. Seems that 08:00 is result of `.utc()` - propably you just need to remove it

Comment: Thank you I tried but couldn't